# Work for a foreign company while on a tourist residence permit in Turkey?

Tags: residency, working, digital-nomads, turkey

I am staying in Turkey on a tourist residence permit (ikamet). I've been told that it's forbidden to work in Turkey on tourist residence permit. I am starting a remote job for an American company soon. My questions are:

1. Is it legal, according to Turkey laws, to work for a foreign company remotely while on tourist residence permit?
2. If it's illegal, will I get into trouble if I get my salary to a Turkish bank account?
3. If it's illegal, will I get into trouble if I get my salary not on a Turkish bank account?

Comment: @Willeke so far I've been in Turkey for 3 weeks. I plan to stay here for something between 6 months and 2 years. Soon I will get a tourist residence permit (ikamet) for 6 months. When these 6 months end, I will be able to renew it.

Comment: According to https://www.mondaq.com/turkey/work-visas/1088062/remote-work-as-a-visitor-in-turkey-during-covid-19 Turkish immigration regulations are silent on the topic of remote working for an overseas employer and it remains as one of the grey areas in Turkish immigration practice.

Comment: did you get a clear answer on this and how are you proceeding now?

Comment: @d33 see my newly written answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some more sources, I learned that there is no clear answer to item 1 "Is it legal, according to Turkey laws, to work for a foreign company remotely while on tourist residence permit?". This is a gray area, there are no official documents or anything like that giving an answer. As for "Will I get into trouble if I get my salary to a Turkish bank account?", I've learned that in practice, the Turkish banks and the Turkish government don't care as long as you get less than $4000 (or its equivalent in another currency) per month sent to your Turkish bank accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm local.

I don't think there is any harm or illegality in working in a foreign country by the way (even remotely).

A few years ago, I heard that a tourist asks him for a residence permit because he wants to open a bank account, and when he wants to get a residence permit, they ask him for a bank account. So, we have an infinite loop in that case. I hope they fixed that already.

For example, this [law firm page says](http://bolgunalhukuk.com/article.php?aId=29), if you want to open a bank account, bank will ask;

- Your passport
- Residence (ikamet) address
- Tax number or if you have residence permit your ID
- Mobile phone number (I think Turkish number)

Last but not least, these are *really* complicated subjects. I **strongly** recommend to get information from legal authorities.

Further reading: [Foreigners and international protection law](https://www.mevzuat.gov.tr/mevzuatmetin/1.5.6458.pdf)